# Can you identifiy this short about teenagers on a raft getting swallowed up by an oil slick?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

In the spirit of all the story identification today, I'm looking for some kind of TV episode about some teenagers who were at a lake.

Slowly, one by one, they get swallowed up by some kind of oil slick looking thing.  It was some kind of dumb creature that lived in a lake swallowing up kids and looked like a black oil slick.  I remember it being part of a show of shorts.  Maybe something like *Tales from Crypt* possibly?  It was probably around 15 - 20 minutes long.  It was pretty cheesy from what I remember; probably something produced in the late 80's or early 90's.  It's something I remember making fun of with my brother when we were young.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are talking about one of the segments from [Creepshow 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepshow_2), I believe.

Stealing from Wikipedia:

**The Raft**

> Four college students, Deke, Laverne, Randy, and Rachel decide to go swimming in a desolate lake far away from civilization. As they make their way to a wooden raft in the middle of the lake, they realize that they are being terrorized by a floating black blob resembling an oil slick when it grabs a hold of Rachel and consumes her.
>
> The frightened students begin to panic. Deke plans to swim to shore so he can bring back help as he is a fast swimmer. But before he can carry out his plan, the blob seeps through the raft's cracks and pulls Deke through the raft, killing him in the process. Randy and Laverne manage to evade the creature long enough to where it gives up trying to grab them from under the raft as well.
>
> Randy and Laverne spend the entire night on the raft, afraid to fall asleep in fear that the creature will attack. They do manage to fall asleep and Randy is the first to wake up in the morning, relieved to find that Laverne and himself made it through the night. With Laverne still sleeping, he begins caressing her body and fondling her breasts. She awakes screaming in agony as the creature has seeped through the cracks and has a hold of her face, much to Randy's horror.
>
> As the oil-like blob pulls her off the raft and begins consuming her, Randy uses the opportunity to jump off the raft and swim to shore. He ultimately makes it, barely escaping the creature and yells "I beat you!" However, the oil creature rises up from the water like a wave and engulfs Randy. The blob returns to the lake, with no evidence of the four students even visiting the lake other than their car which was left running the whole time. The camera pans out to reveal a "No Swimming" sign barely visible from behind some growth.

Comment: It would be simply called "The Raft", thanks.

Answer (score 12):

It is The Raft, the 2nd story segment from 1987's Creepshow 2.

It's based on the 1982 Stephen King [short story](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/The_Raft) of the same name, that was later published in his 2nd short story collection 'Skeleton Crew'.

The film is actually fairly faithful to the short story, other than a change to the ending, they are very similar.

Comment: Correct but I bet you don't know the ghost writer.

Comment: +1 for identifying the original SK short story as well.